# Laravel Vue Pusher: Broadcast To Others

Tags: vuejs2, laravel-5.4, pusher

I created a chat using laravel, vue and pusher. The chat it's working, but when i send a message, it send'it twice. 
I set `broadcast(new MessagePosted($message, $user))->toOthers()` but still not working properly.
If you have any suggestions please don't hesitate.

Comment: can you show me the code in your vue component ?
does it get save twice in your db?

Comment: are you using Laravel Echo for transmitting message ?